# Erro com ao tentar inserir informações com rotas

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Em `api.php` tenho esse código:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function() {
   Route::post('clube/addClube', function(Request $request) {
       return App\clubes::addClube(['name' => $request -> input(['name'])]);
   });
});
```

No meu arquivo eu tenho esse método:

```
methods: {
    addLine(){
       this.list.push({clube: this.clube});
       this.$http.post('api/clube/addClube', this.clube);
    }
}
```

E no meu Modal clubes.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class BD extends Model
{

}
```

E retorna esse erro `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

Comment: Eu acho que te falta usar `vue-resource`. `npm install vue-resource --save`. Em app.js: `import VueResource from 'vue-resource';` e `Vue.use(VueResource);`. Pois ao que parece a função $http não existe

Comment: Mesmo instalando e importando http://prntscr.com/g6e9kc, ainda sim continua o erro.